# Integration: What functions can we substitute?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I was tutoring a girl in Calculus the other day and she asked me a really good question: What functions can we use for substitution in the integral?

We of course require differentiability but I imagine much less is needed. My instinct form multivariable is that we probably need a diffeomorphism almost everywhere (like polar coordinates on the punctured plane). Is this correct?

If this is a silly question and there are materials that I somehow missed, let me know!

Comment: There is a great difference between substitution on the line or on $\mathbb R^n$. If I remember right, you could get away with an absolutely continuous function on the line.

Comment: Cf https://sites.ualberta.ca/~rjia/Math418/Notes/chap3.pdf

Comment: Substitutions are given by diffeomorphisms, i.e. invertible and differentiable maps, you're correct.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio but do they have to be diffeomorphisms on the whole domain of integration?

Comment: and as far as the close vote goes, it would be helpful if you mentioned why you thought it was too broad. I can add: "What are the necessary and  conditions for the substitution of a function for the dummy variable of integration"

Comment: @qbert: no, subsets of the domain with measure zero do not matter, clearly.